# enviar array de ajax a php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

hola a todos  tengo el siguiente formulario en el que agrego productos y al darle click en agregar se almacenan en la tabla como en la imagen,
como pueden ver en la imagen tengo 3 productos y  al darle click en vista previa lo que hace es almacenar todos los registros de la tabla en un array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo

> JQuery(ajax)

```
$('#btnbtn').on('click',function(){
                /*(nose si es la mejor manera de almacenar los datos de mi tabla en un array, 
                si alguien sabe una mejor manera ,le estaria muy agradecido) ↓*/
               var datosArray=new Array();
                $('#tablaProductosIngresados > #tablaPI').each(function () {
                var codigoArray = $(this).find('td').eq(0).html();
                var descripcionArray = $(this).find('td').eq(1).html();
                var unidadMedidaArray = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
                var PrecioUniArray= $(this).find('td').eq(3).html();
                var cantidadArray = $(this).find('td').eq(4).html();
                var descuentoArray = $(this).find('td').eq(5).html();
                var totalArray = $(this).find('td').eq(6).html();
                var itemArray = $(this).find('td').eq(8).html();
                var tipoExistenciaArray = $(this).find('td').eq(9).html();
                 var fechaVigenciaArray = $(this).find('td').eq(10).html();

                 valor=new Array(codigoArray, descripcionArray, unidadMedidaArray,PrecioUniArray,cantidadArray,descuentoArray,totalArray,itemArray,tipoExistenciaArray,fechaVigenciaArray);

                  datosArray.push(valor);


                 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(valor);

                   // console.log(jsonString);
                     $.ajax({
                          url:'insertVistaPrevia.php',
                          type:'POST',
                          data:{btnbtn:jsonString},    
                          cache: false,
                          success:function(data){

                           console.log(data);                         
                          } 

                     });
                      return false;
                });
              })
```

y asi los recibo en mi codigo php

> php

```
<?php 
$data = json_decode($_POST['btnbtn']);

foreach ($data as $datos) {

    echo $datos;


}?>
```

mi problema es que solo me muestra el primer registro de mi tabla

nose como poner mi codigo de la tabla ya que se generan columnas conforme se le da click a un boton de agregar .....

he buscado y todos dicen que se hace con """JSON.stringify"""

pero no me sale ,espero que me ayuden

Comment: que te sale en el log? de console.log(jsonString)

Comment: 123 12 gl  123 12 21739.32  ... el primer td ,como esta en la imagen ,pero los demas no,,,yo creo que es la manera de como lo almacene en el array, espero que me puedas ayudar

Comment: esa linea no debería de ser con datosArray? 

 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(datosArray);

Comment: no , si lo pongo asi me marca error

Answer (score 0):

Esta sería la síntesis correcta:

```
data: {
    "codigoArray": codigoArray, 
    "descripcionArray": descripcionArray,
    "unidadMedidaArray": unidadMedidaArray,
    "cantidadArray": cantidadArray,
    "nombre": "Iván",
    "codigo": "1234"
}
```

Código PHP:

```
$dataCodigo = $_POST['codigoArray'];
$dataDescripcion = $_POST['descripcionArray'];
$dataUnidad = $_POST['unidadMedidaArray'];
$dataCantidad = $_POST['cantidadArray'];

echo $dataCodigo;
echo $dataDescripcion;
echo $dataUnidad;
echo $dataCantidad;
```

Esto debido a que la [tecnología AJAX en data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) permite utilizar un objeto JSON, un array o un query string.

Comment: ¿Puedes decir por qué sería la correcta?

Comment: Si, perdona. La tecnología AJAX en data permite utilizar un objeto JSON, un array o un query string.                                        
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: hola ivan, no me sale como indicas :/

Comment: si fuera asi, como los recibiria en el archivo php? me marca error

Comment: por favor explicame bien , si no fuerma mucha molestia

Comment: He editado el código. He añadido el código php

Answer (score 0):

logre hacer lo que necesitaba (pasar un array de js a php) logre converirlo a json para pasarlo a php de la siguiente manera, si es que a alguien le llega a suceder.

> js

```
              function articulo (codigo, descripcion,unidadMedida,PrecioUnitario,cantidad,descuento,total,item,tipoExistencia,fechaVigencia )
                {
                    this.codigo = codigo;
                    this.descripcion = descripcion;
                    this.unidadMedida = unidadMedida;
                    this.PrecioUnitario = PrecioUnitario;
                    this.cantidad = cantidad;
                    this.descuento = descuento;
                    this.total = total;
                    this.item = item;
                    this.tipoExistencia = tipoExistencia;
                    this.fechaVigencia = fechaVigencia;
                }

              $('#btnbtn').on('click',function(){                   
               var datosArray=new Array();
                $('#tablaProductosIngresados > #tablaPI').each(function () {
                 valor=new Array($(this).find('td').eq(0).html(),
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(1).html(),
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(2).html(), 
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(3).html(), 
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(4).html(), 
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(5).html(), 
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(6).html(), 
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(8).html(), 
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(9).html(),
                                 $(this).find('td').eq(10).html());
                 datosArray.push(valor);
                });

                        var i, n = datosArray.length;
                        var tmp = new Array();
                        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
                        {
                            tmp[i] = new articulo( datosArray[i][0], datosArray[i][1], datosArray[i][2], datosArray[i][3], datosArray[i][4], datosArray[i][5], datosArray[i][6], datosArray[i][7], datosArray[i][8], datosArray[i][9] );
                        }
                        var mObj = new Object;
                        mObj.datosArray = tmp;
                        var objJSON = JSON.stringify(mObj);
                        //console.log(objJSON);

                        $.ajax({
                          url:'insertVistaPrevia.php',
                          type:'POST',
                          data:{data:objJSON},    
                          cache: false,
                          success:function(data){

                             console.log(data); 

                          } 

                     });
                      return false;



              })
```